# Uniswap V3 - How to make a Multicall

Tags: web3js, uniswap, swaps

I am using Uniswap V3 and want to web3 call

1. `exactOutputSingle()`
2. `refundETH()`

I want them in once transaction in order to let the user confirm only one time on the wallet.

I know there is the Multicall contract from where SwapRouter derives.
So how can I do a multicall in web3 and how to encode the functions for the Multicall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a working example for a multicall Uniswap V3:

```
    var calls = [];
    const swap = swapRouter.methods.exactOutputSingle([token1, 
                                                        token0, 
                                                        fee, 
                                                        owner, 
                                                        deadline, 
                                                        amountOut, 
                                                        quotedAmountIn, 
                                                        0]).encodeABI();

    const refund = swapRouter.methods.refundETH().encodeABI();
    calls.push(swap);
    calls.push(refund);

    try {
        await swapRouter.methods.multicall(calls).send({from: owner, gas: 1000000, value: quotedAmountIn}); 
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```